# Creating JOOQ query dynamically

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to create a JOOQ SELECT query dynamically based on the set of parameters. I dont know how to append it dynamically.
Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? E.g. could you provide an example query that you would like to construct? What have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: Actually i need to create the select query; wherein i need to update the where clause based upon the parameters passed. Like from the UI I am passing some filters and want to add to my WHERE  condition dynamically.

Answer (score 35):

jOOQ has two types of APIs to construct queries.

- The DSL API that allows for creating inline SQL statements in your Java code, e.g.

  ```
  create.select(T.A, T.B).from(T).where(T.X.eq(3).and(T.Y.eq(5)));
  ```
- The "model" API that allows for incremental SQL building. At any time, you can access the "model" API through the [`getQuery()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectFinalStep.html#getQuery--) method on a DSL query object

An example of what you want to do is given in the manual here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/

For instance, optionally adding a join:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(configuration);
SelectQuery query = create.selectQuery();
query.addFrom(AUTHOR);

// Join books only under certain circumstances
if (join)
    query.addJoin(BOOK, BOOK.AUTHOR_ID.equal(AUTHOR.ID));

Result<?> result = query.fetch();
```

Or, optinally adding conditions / predicates:

```
query.addConditions(BOOK.TITLE.like("%Java%"));
query.addConditions(BOOK.LANGUAGE_CD.eq("en"));
```

**UPDATE:** Given your comments, that's what you're looking for:

```
// Retrieve search strings from your user input (just an example)
String titleSearchString = userInput.get("TITLE");
String languageSearchString = userInput.get("LANGUAGE");
boolean lookingForTitles = titleSearchString != null;
boolean lookingForLanguages = languageSearchString != null;

// Add only those conditions that the user actually provided:
if (lookingForTitles)
    query.addConditions(BOOK.TITLE.like("%" + titleSearchString + "%"));
else if (lookingForLanguages)
    query.addConditions(BOOK.LANGUAGE_CD.eq(languageSearchString));
```

Note, you can also use the [`Field.compare(Comparator, Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#compare-org.jooq.Comparator-T-) methods:

```
// Initialise your dynamic arguments
Field<String> field = BOOK.TITLE;
Comparator comparator = Comparator.LIKE;
String value = "%" + titleSearchString + "%";

// Pass them to the field.compare() method
query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, value));
```

For more info, consider the [org.jooq.SelectQuery](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html) Javadoc

Comment: But i have one more question. Can i use java variables in the query(specifically in the addConditions part), so that i can put the value of those variables at run time. for eg. column name.

Comment: @user1900723: What keeps you from assigning those elements to variables in Java?

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario. Actually I have some columns which I have to search in the table. For example: Name, ID, Date. and I need to fetch the data according to them, having one other paramater which contains the values like EQUAL TO, BEGINS WITH(need to use like operator), ENDS WITH(need to use like operator). I need to do all this dynamically. So, need to use variable so that i can put the value on fly. Please let me know if you need further clarification. I am stuck here.

Comment: @user1900723: I understand what you're trying to do. But what have you already tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Feel free to update (edit) your question to add more information

Comment: I actually can't understand how to dynamically add those EQUAL and LIKE function inside the addConditions function. It would be great if you can give me a very brief sample code. As what i read so far is that we can make Jooq query at runtime using SelectQuery factory and can also add conditions and joins on the fly. But how to add these operators(Like and Equal).

Comment: @user1900723: I'm not sure what the trouble is...? You'll just have to write some custom API around jOOQ to implement the DAO layer...? See the updated answer

Comment: Like in the normal Mysql query what I would do is I check the parameter whether it is Equals, Ends with, Begins with and accordingly i would append the where clause using "=" or like operator respectively. As it is merely a string so i can append it easily. The same i want to do it in  Jooq.

Comment: @user1900723: OK, I've given you enough information, I think. You can try yourself now. If you find a different solution, feel free to post an answer here on Stack Overflow. I suggest you also read the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), which will help you to get more concise answers more easily, in the future

Comment: @LukasEder Can we make use dslcontext.execute() method using plain Select SQL? That way only need to construct dynamic String SQL query.  This could also be one of the way to achieve above use case