# How to use JOOQ Model API to add dynamic Conditions from String based column names?

Tags: java, sql, dynamic, conditional-statements, jooq

I am using the JOOQ Model API to dynamically build a query.  It is similar to what is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051080/creating-jooq-query-dynamically):

However, I need this query to have dynamic conditions based on columns names and values I am passing in as Strings.  I know in my repository what the table is from a private getTable() method.

```
String fieldName = "my_column";
String fieldValue = "searchTerm";

SelectQuery<Record> query = create.selectQuery();
query.addFrom(getTable());
```

Instead of doing something like this...

```
query.addConditions(BOOK.TITLE.like(fieldValue + "%"));
```

I need a generalized way to get table fields by name...

```
query.addConditions(getTable().getTableField(fieldName).like(fieldValue + "%"));
```

I couldn't find anything on the generated table or record classes that did this.  The table class has the TableField static members I need to use, but no way to look them up by name.  Is there something else available I am missing?

If not, I see two courses of action.  I prefer the first:

1. Customize the generator somehow to create some kind of internal lookup on the generated Table class.
2. I could create new TableFieldImpl instances, but that seems like a waste when generated TableImpl classes already have them and I would need to know everything about the table column in order to create it properly.

EDIT:  I think what I want may be [DSL.condition()](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which can take a SQL string and bound parameters or you can create a condition like this:

```
query.addConditions(DSL.condition("? = ?", fieldName,fieldValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is called [`TableLike.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-java.lang.String-) and it is thus present on all table expressions in the jOOQ API. For instance:

```
query.addConditions(getTable().field(fieldName).like(fieldValue + "%"));
```

Now, this won't work out of the box, because the `Field<?>` reference's wildcard will prevent you from comparing that `Field` with `fieldValue + "%"`. You have these options:

#### jOOQ 3.5 and less

```
getTable().field(fieldName).coerce(String.class).like(fieldValue + "%")
((Field<String>) getTable().field(fieldName)).like(fieldValue + "%")
```

#### jOOQ 3.6

```
getTable().field(fieldName, String.class).like(fieldValue + "%")
```

Comment: Thank you.  After trying it out with different comparisons I would recommend this: getTable().field(fieldName).coerce(String.class).like(DSL.field("'" + fieldValue  + "%'", String.class))  which works with equal,greaterThan, and other classes like Integer, Double, Date, etc.  However, you don't need the single quotes with the non-string classes.

Comment: Please don't do that: `DSL.field("'" + fieldValue + "%'", String.class)` This will 1) prevent usage of bind variables, 2) [create a SQL injection vulnerability](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/05/using-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-to-dump-your-database/)

Comment: Then how would you make this work with other comparisons besides like?

Comment: If you ask another question on Stack Overflow, I'll be more than happy to answer that. I guess this will be easier in a new question rather than in comments :)